# Short trick to find the number of Sylow p subgroups in permutation groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I know, $|S_4 |=24 =2^3\cdot3$.

So here the order of sylow $2$ subgroup is $8$ and by the third sylow theorem we can say the number of sylow $2$ subgroups is $1$ or $3$. Then by finding the sylow $2$ subgroups explicitly we can conclude that its $3$. But here we also know the number of sylow $3$ subgroups is $1$ or $4$.

> My question is can we find the exact number of sylow $2$ and $3$ subgroups without calculating the the sylow subgroups explicitly, just by element counting of the subgroups, because sometimes we need only the exact number in of sylow subgroups ?

Comment: The number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $|G:N_G(P)|$, where $P$ is some specific Sylow $p$-subgroup. This avoids having to calculate them all explicitly - you just need to find one of them and compute its normalizer.

Comment: Thank you, I got this very useful because this thing can be used for any group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $S_4$ has a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup say $K$. By Sylow Second Theorem, $K$ must be normal in $S_4$. But $S_4$ does not have any normal subgroup of order $8$ (Refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484889/s-4-does-not-have-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-8)). Therefore the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups in $S_4$ must be three.

Comment: Thank you. Here for permutation group we know particular normal subgroup as An where n is not 4, so thank you so much for giving this idea, I have one more question, for other groups where this kind of normal subgroup may present , there can we say any tricky observation like this ?